# Need help in implementing DICOM in JAVA

Tags: java, dicom

I want to implement Dicom using JAVA.
      And also i should not use any existing API and i have to develop from the scratch.
      I spent almost 10 days in understanding DICOM itself,i got some vague idea
      so kindly help how implement it in java , where to start,architechture etc...

Answer (score 4):

I agree with malat. DICOM is a complex beast and re-implementing everything from scratch is likely not the way to go.

I would also add [dcm4che](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dcm4che/files/dcm4che2/) as a toolkit which can be used to process, create and manipulate DICOM objects in Java.

Comment: This is how I started. It works to learn it via dcm4che :) Took me about 3 years additionally to the main job.

Answer (score 3):

I would read the source code of other open-source projects such as:

- GDCM
- DCMTK
- dicom3tools

DICOM can be very subtle, I would say it will take you 3-5 years of experience to understand all the details and fix all your bugs. You should avoid re-inventing the wheel.